# Como mandar uma matriz criada de forma dinâmica como parâmetro para uma função?

Tags: c, funções, malloc

No execício que estou desenvolvendo tento passar uma matriz criada de forma dinâmica criada com a função `malloc`, mas ao fazer isso o compilador aponta como tipo incompatível com ponteiro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void substituiNegativos(int c, int mat[][c]){

    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i< 2; i++){
        for(j=0; j< 2; j++){

            if(mat[i][j] < 0){
                mat[i][j] = abs(mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i< 2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<2; j++){

            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{

    int i, j, l, c;

    printf("Numero de linhas: ");
    scanf("%d", &l);

    printf("Numero de colunas: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    int **mat = (int**)malloc(l * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<l; i++){

        mat[i] = (int*)malloc(c * sizeof(int));

        for(j=0; j<c; j++){

            printf("Insira o numero: ");
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    substituiNegativos(c, mat);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em C, no argumento da função, você precisa dizer para o compilador quantas colunas você tem em sua matriz, devido ao fato de que a matriz nada mais é que um vetor, porem com uma lógica de linhas e colunas, exemplo:

```
int main()
{
    int matriz[3][3] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

o resultado será isso:

```
Matriz[i][j] -> 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
         [i] -> 0  0  0  1  1  1  2  2  2
         [j] -> 1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
```

O compilador precisa saber que para tal linha ele tem um agrupamento de **X** posições de memória (colunas) com valores, por isso, ele exige que declare, ao menos, a quantidade de colunas. Para resolver seu problema, você pode declarar uma quantidade de colunas. Exemplo:

```
void substituiNegativos(int c, int mat[][100])
```

Ou, então, declarar um ponteiro de vetor. Exemplo:

```
void substituiNegativos(int c, int *mat[])
```

Qualquer um dos dois vai funcionar.

Comment: Agradeço pela explicação, funcionou, mas também gostaria de saber mais por curiosidade, se eu poderia passar o argumento dessa forma `void substituiNegativos(int c, int mat[][c])`, sendo a variável `c` meu tamanho de coluna, ou C não permite isso. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Não permite por dois motivos: 
1 - Sua variável 'c' é local dentro da função 'main'. Ela só é vista dentro da 'main'.
2 - 'c' não representa valor nenhum no escopo da função 'void substituiNegativos(int c, int mat[][c])'. Como eu havia explicado, é necessário declarar um valor na coluna da matriz em um escopo de função

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito.